# Cannot resolve method in calling class, but method exists (and compiles) in both the interface and implementation classes

Tags: java, selenium, interface

I'm writing a suite of Selenium tests in Java. Part of the program relies on a class called `ResponseInterceptor.java`, which uses methods from both my `IReporter.java` interface and `Reporter.java` implementation class. I am getting a `Cannot resolve method "reportDone" in "IReporter"` error. The problem is that `reportDone()` exists, and compiles, in both the interface and the implementation class. I have made sure the given paramenters match the method signature. I have also tried importing `IReporter` and `Reporter`, but this did not work either. In addition, I created a new method in the interface, implemented it, and called it from `ResponseInterceptor`, and the new method works just fine. This made me think that if I just copied the method and gave it a new name, implementing and calling it the same way as `reportDone()`, that would work. It did not. The files are all in the same directory, if that matters.

Here is the method call in `ResponseInterceptor`:

```
Browser.getReporter().reportDone(String.format("Response: %s", responseCode),
    String.format("StatusCode= %s :: URL= %s :: Header= %s :: Body= %s", statusCode, url, headers, responseBody));
```

Here is its definition in `IReporter`:

```
void reportDone(String stepName, String stepDescription);
```

Here is its implementation in `Reporter`:

```
public void reportDone(String stepName, String stepDescription) {
    report.updateTestLog(stepName, stepDescription, Status.DONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. There were two IReporter classes. I simply had to cast the procedures to the correct IReporter, like so:

```
((automation.IReporter)Browser.getReporter().reportDone(String.format(...
```